# What is the relationship between threads and frames per second?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am currently working on a game. I have a render thread, the main thread, and a bunch of other threads that do calculations on the side.

Typical Frame Setup as follows:

1. Do stuff on main thread. Add work to be done on worker threads.
2. Do stuff on render thread.
3. Wait for render thread to finish.
4. Go back to 1.

Throughout the frame, there are various calculations being done on the worker threads.

When I run the game, there are some points where I am not getting the ideal 60 FPS. Through some debugging and profiling, I have come to the conclusion that the main thread and render thread combined only contribute to about 8 milliseconds, which should give me about 120 FPS.

I have also noticed that I tend to see FPS drops when the worker threads are doing more work.

NOTE : The FPS is calculated based on the time difference between each frame on the main thread.

I would have thought that the FPS should only depend on the performance of the main thread and render thread.

Also note that the time the main thread and render threads spend waiting for the worker threads is negligible.

So what am I missing? Why does the FPS drop when the worker threads are doing more work, despite the FPS not relying upon those threads?

**EDIT** : The main thread as well as a websocket thread submit work to be done on the worker threads.

After more profiling, it seems that the CPU is just waiting (not sure why) for a while after the render thread finishes its work until it starts back at the main thread again. Note that I am using Unity3D, but am doing a lot of custom stuff in a C++ plugin.

Comment: If your main goal is to boost FPS, you might want to look into double buffering or even triple buffering.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing some code, but given that you have a multi-threaded program and the more work your worker threads are doing, perhaps synchronization primitives (mutexes, semaphores, etc) are the culprit?

Comment: @Gogeta70 -   Synchronisation primitives may be involved, but will not typically be the culprit.   The culprit would be code that uses those primitives (e.g. one threads holds a mutex unnecessarily, and forces another thread to wait).  Speaking in general terms (without code), synchronisation primitives should only be used to synchronise access to data that is shared between threads - which is necessary for correctness - but an easy trap is doing additional calculations in that critical code, and therefore forcing other threads to wait.

Comment: @Peter That's what I was getting at, I suppose I should have been a bit clearer on my meaning. If the render thread is waiting on worker threads, then things will slow down.

Comment: How many synchronization points do you have (Ideally, one)? Perhaps if you give us the outline of your inner loop in code it'll be more obvious where you have issues.

Comment: What do you do in worker threads? Who submits work to them? Does it wait for work to be done? I could recommend profiling your code with vTune (with user events). It'll create you a nice timeline for each thread and it could give you hint which thread waits for other.

Comment: Would a locked mutex on one thread cause slowdowns on another thread that isn't currently locking that mutex?

Comment: "_not sure why_" Be sure why. Mutexes and locks? If they aren't needed, rid yourself of them.

Comment: @JoshuaWilde "Would a locked mutex on one thread cause slowdowns on another thread that isn't currently locking that mutex?" No, it won't.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of shared resources in a typical modern computer system that makes the cores not independent.

To start with, the CPU is a single physical object that has a temperature. If the CPU gets too hot or is drawing too much power, various techniques will minimize power consumption at the expense of performance. Clock speed boosting technologies take these factors into account. Some directly limit based on the number of cores that are active.

CPUs also have shared resources such as L2 and L3 caches and memory bandwidth. Active cores can consume these resources leaving less for other cores.

Lastly, poor software design can create dependencies where they shouldn't be. False sharing, for example, can cause software on one core to make software on another core operate less efficiently. Poorly designed synchronization primitives (such as naive, home-made spinlocks) can saturate inter-core buses resulting in poor performance.

Comment: The reminder of CPU as physical object with temperature is golden. Software engineers (myself included!) tend to completely forget about physical aspect of their hardware, but are affected by it!

Comment: @SergeyA It would amaze me that people would even forget that... Didn't one already state that E=MC^2? The amount of Energy is proportionately equal to the product of the amount of mass and the area or velocity of light with in a specific system or environment?

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

Focus on seconds (really, milliseconds) per frame, not frames per second. Depending on your driver, rendering API, framework (if present), etc., your game can get throttled back to 60FPS, 30FPS, etc. to keep presents smooth if you're occasionally, or barely, missing the target. For example: the Oculus runtime will throttle from 90Hz to 45Hz if you are not consistently rendering in 11ms.

> 3. Wait for render thread to finish.

Don't let the main thread (frequently called the "game thread") wait on the render thread to complete. That defeats much of the purpose of using separate threads. Unity and Unreal both use separate game and render threads. In Unity, the game thread pushes rendering commands (or jobs) into a queue, and the render thread pulls from that queue. It's possible to insert time stamps (or whatever) into the queue so that, if the render thread gets too far behind, it can fast-forward to the most recent frame instead of rendering old data.

Likewise, the render thread should not wait on the other threads. It's better if the game stops updating, but does not freeze, than the other way around.

From your description of the system, it's not clear what your "worker threads" are doing. You say that this issue is intermittent. Is it related to the amount of work being done at that time, or does it appear completely random?

Does your profiling indicate that the issue is on the CPU (main thread & worker threads) or GPU?

Some things to look at:

1. Memory management. Heap thrashing is the enemy of performance. If you're frequently allocating / deallocating non-primitives in a tight loop, this can become a serious issue. (Also, look for memory leaks.)
2. Context rolls. Since your main thread is waiting on the render thread, a delay caused by a context roll will propagate through the rest of the system.
3. Content. What are you rendering, and how? I've worked on a project where someone was trying to render an entire VERY high-poly palace as one monolithic model, while the player walked around inside said palace. This made frustum culling useless. Perf was, shall we say, suboptimal.
4. Content, part 2: How much data are you sending to the GPU each frame? CPU-to-GPU bandwidth is limited. If you're refreshing large vertex buffers or textures every frame, performance will suffer dramatically.
5. Grab a tool like GPUView and record some logs. GPUView is not my favorite tool, but it'll give you an idea if this is a CPU or GPU problem. On AMD with DX12 or Vulkan, RGP (Radeon Graphics Profiler) is amazing. Nvidia also has some really awesome tools for this.

In short:

Figure out which thread is causing the problem, and where. That will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

> *- There are many major components to any complex working 3D Graphics Engine along with the accompanying Game Application that is built upon that Engine -*

---

Here is a list of things to consider:

> - *1<sup>st</sup>* - Is the `Game Source Code` tightly tided into the Game Engine?
>
>   - Meaning, if you were to strip out the `Game Logic`, `Game Properties`, `Game Settings`, and `Loaded Game Assets`; would the `Game Engine Break`?
>   - Or is `ALL` of the `Game Engine` built upon a `Framework` that is `Abstracted` away from all of the `Game Contents` to be a complete `Generic` and `Reusable` `Library`?
> - *2<sup>nd</sup>* - The `System's Current Hardware And Configurations`
>
>   - The `OS` that the machine is based on.
>   - The `Installed` & `Running` `Appications` and `APIs`.
>   - The most recently `Installed`, `Updated`, & `Supported` `Drivers`.
> - *3<sup>rd</sup>* - What kind of `Framework` are you using for your `Memory Module`?
>
>   - `BSP`, `OCT TREES`, `Marching Cubes`, etc.
> - *4<sup>th</sup>* - What kind of `Content` is being loaded?
>
>   - What type of contents are they?
>   - How much is being loaded into memory?
>   - What are their file sizes?
>   - How are they being stored in memory.
>   - What kind of containers are being used:
>
>     - `vector`, `map`, `list`, `array`, etc.},
>   - Are you `opening`, `reading`, and `loading` in the same files multiple times?
>   - If you create a specific resource and it is used multiple times in the game, are you loading that up as multiple instances into memory?
>   - Or are you creating just one instance and using that as a reference while sharing it as if it were more than one object?
>
>     - Example: You have a loaded mesh for a car in memory, you have 3 cars that are of the same type in your scene but they each have different colors: one blue, one red and the other black; Are you storing 3 separate meshes into dynamic memory for each one, or are you storing one instance in memory and referencing that memory to apply some kind of color transformation(s), before sending it to be rendered?
>   - The files that are being read in:
>   - Are they `Compressed` `Raw Data`, `Text`, or `Binary`?
>   - Do they have some form of `Encryption`?
>   - Are you using modern `APIs` with `Shaders` and if so what kind of `Shaders`?
> - *5<sup>th</sup>* - Now that we mentioned `Shaders`, this leads into the draw calls, or render frames:
>
>   - What type of structure do you have for your Rendering System?
>   - If you have animations, physics and or particles engines integrated into your Graphics Rendering Engine, are you synchronizing your `FPS` callback rate with your `Physics Time Step Refresh Rate`?
> - *6<sup>th</sup>* - The over all Scene:
>
>   - How is your `Scene Graph` structured?
>   - How are you handling lighting?
>   - How are you handling shading?
>   - Vertices call draws:
>
>     - Drawing all vertices, using index vertices, or streaming vertices?
>     - Are there a bottleneck(s) between your `Vertex`, `Fragment or Pixel`, `Geometry` or `Compute` `Shader(s)`?
>     - Are you using a `Stencils` or `Scissors`?
>   - How are you handling `Z-Depth`, `Transparency`, `Backface` and `Frustum` `Culling`?
> - *7<sup>th</sup>* - Programming Techniques:
>
>   - Are you programming with just `Multi Threading` or are you also utilizing `Parallel Programming`?
>   - Are you getting `Cache` misses, or are you `Trashing` your `Cache`?
>   - Are your common structures `WORD` `Aligned`? Most common 4-byte alignment.
>   - Are you handling `Little - Big Endian` correctly?
>   - How often are you `Casting` from one type to another and back?
>   - Are you finding `critical sections` of `code` within high priority `loops` and utilizing `asm` blocks?
>   - What is your trade off between short lived objects on the `stack` versus game length objects that are almost always in `dynamic` memory?
>   - Again back to what kind of containers are you using and what kind of algorithms are being used to search, sort, find, add, & remove elements from them?
> - *8<sup>th</sup>* - Regarding the system itself:
>
>   - What kind of `Background Applications` are running?
>   - What priority does your `Engines` `Main` `Executable-Thread` have?
>   - Is your `Antivirus` running a scan?
>   - Is your `OS` `Updating` some `Application` or `Driver`?
>   - Is there heavy `Traffic` over your `Network`?
> - *9<sup>th</sup>* - Rendering Types:
>
>   - Are you drawing your frames in `Software` or `Hardware`?
>
>     - If in `Hardware` are you making draw calls over the `CPU` such as in `Legacy OpenGL 1.0`, or are you utilizing modern `APIs` and sending the draw calls to a dedicated graphics card (`GPU`)?
>     - Is that graphics card an actual card such as a `PCI-Express` or is it an `Integrated Graphics Chip`?
> - *10<sup>th</sup>* - GPU Over CPU And Batch Rendering:
>
>   - If you are using the `GPU`; One of the most important things that is over looked is how are you sending your `vertex buffer`, `color data`, etc. to the graphics card?
>   - Are you sending a single model to be draw in frame each & every frame?
>   - Or are you assigning them to a priority queue to send multiple objects of similar types in a single pass?
>
>     - For example: You have a frame function that is being called about 60 times per seconds and in this function you have a for loop that is going through a bunch of 3D models with all of their vertex data, color-texture data, normal data etc...
>     - Are calling their own render or draw call function on each frame pass?
>     - Or do you combine similar primitive types into one large bucket and send that bucket either when it has the highest priority, is filled, or all other buckets are filled and it is the fullest?
>     - This process is called `Batch Rendering`. This makes things a lot more efficient since the `GPU` is much faster than the `CPU`. It can do a lot more work than the `CPU` can, however sending that information over the `BUS` is considered a fairly slow process...
>     - So if you are in a frame and you call a render on a Truck mesh, then call render on a Tree mesh, then you call render on a House mesh, etc. and let's say you have about 3,000 of these render calls in this single frame; these all have to be sorted and accounted for within the World-View-Projection Matrices so that it can properly render these objects to the screen at the right location, orientation and scale of the scene in the correct order based on Z-Depth and Transparency information.
>     - As you can see this can get very cumbersome quite quickly. So there is quite a bit of work being done here.
>     - Understanding this: if you presort your data before sending it to the frame buffer, and if you are using a batch renderer (instead of having 3000 render calls for each object); all similar objects will be grouped into a bucket where you have sets of buckets in a priority queue waiting to be rendered or sent to the `GPU`. When the time is right the appropriate bucket(s) will get(s) dispatched to the `GPU` for object rendering.
>
> *There is so much more than just what I've mentioned as this is only the `Tip` of the `Iceberg`... I briefly mentioned on `Physics`, `Animations`, `Particle Systems` and the like, but I never mentioned things like `Terrains`, `Skyboxes-Domes`, `Dynamic Weathering`, `Ecological Systems`, `Sound` and `Music`, `Networking`, etc... And this is only on the `Engine` side of things; this is all absent of any `Game Loading`, `Game Logic`, `Game Level`, `Game Properties`, `Game Settings`, `Game Rules`, etc.*

---

*-Tips-*

It is not all that simple to give a direct relationship to threads and the frames per second as there are many components, variables and factors involved. Is your frame and render calls within a thread; or do you have many threads in your frame function? If you appear to be getting bottlenecks in your application; step through your debugger and try to narrow it down to what critical intensive loop is giving you the slow down. Do some profiling and bench mark tests around different loops; try to change the data sets in the loops or the amount of data to see if that has an effect. Make sure you don't have any extraneous background applications running so that your bench marks are unbiased... Try your code on various machines and platforms... and see if it yields the same results.

One of the last issues or concerns would be this: You have your main thread that runs the Engine's executable, it spawns off other threads; one for rendering, one for processing audio, one for loading in object (mesh-model) files, etc. How are these threads synchronized; are you getting race conditions? Are you using mutexes, semaphores or fences, etc.? These can all have minimal to dramatic effects on your FPS not counting all of the above that I have mentioned!

---

*-Pseudo Code Example:-*

Either your Game Engine is written with the intent of running in a Single Thread on a Single Core, or it is designed with the purpose to run on multiple threads and or cores and even in parallel.

The bottom line is this: Your Game Engine - Game Code in your main would look something like this in general:

```
#include "Game.h" // Game.h includes Engine.h as it inherits from Engine.

int main () { 
    try {
        Game game;
        game.run();
    } catch(...) {
        // Display Exception: Error MSGs -Exit Error        
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`Game.run()` would call `Engine's` `frame()`, the OS's `messageHandler()` - system (I/O), and would continue until the user decides to quit.

```
Game::run() {
    while( /*user not quit*/ ) {
        frame();
    }
}

Engine:frame() {
    // getMessageHandlers(); // Get Keyboard - Mouse Input & Process it

    // game.update(); // handle time, physics calculations etc.

    // batchManager->renderBatches();
}
```

---

*-Conclusion-*

If there is no multithreading within the Engine - Game itself; then it is not an integrated part of but abstracted out of the Engine and the overall design would be a single threaded application. Although you can run the game-engine it in its own thread while the main.cpp spawns other independent threads, it would still be considered a single threaded component.

Or you could have multithreading all throughout your Game Engine which it then would be tailored with the intentions of running on multiple cores-threads... In this case it would be an integrated part of the Engine, and all components of the Engine will have an impact on your overall Frames Per Second!

---

> *Not only in theory but in practice if you are using multi-threading in your application framework, then the relationship to your FPS is in truth Paramount as it is an integrated part of your overall Game Engine Structure & Design.*

---

Now as pertaining to your overall assessment: It may not be related to your threads at all; it could have to do with how many objects are being rendered in the Scene at a given moment, if you have back face culling on or off, and frustum calling on and off, it also depends on the scale of your frustum z-depth and view angle. It also depends on how much detail is in your meshes textures; how you are calculating your vertices and their normals, It can depend on how many lights you have; what types of lighting you are using. It may not even bee on your `c++` side; it could be a bottleneck in your shaders: Remember that the fragment shader gets called a lot more than the vertex shader in the programmable shader pipeline.

One tip or suggestion is to set your variable that reports the current FPS to a watch point, and break on the condition if it decreases below a certain threshold for more than a certain given amount of time; your break condition might look something like this:

```
while ( FPS < 60 ) {
  timeDifference = calculateElapsedTime();         
}

if ( timeDifference > X ) {
    set your break point;
}
```

From here you should be able to sep into or out of your application to narrow down the bottleneck.

At first thought I thought it might of been a race condition; but it appears you have ruled that out...

Comment: This answer is FAQ material. I  can't upvote more than once.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I understand. The OP asked a basic yet tough question where no source code was provided. It's more of a scenario than a specific problem, although it is commonly reoccurring. Q&As like these are mostly frowned upon here at SO.  Problems like this are quite common in all different kinds of applications regarding multithreading, and this serves as an overall assessment on how to treat it, what to consider, what to look for, and how to improve or optimize it. In some cases; these kinds of Q&As can serve as a great reference material not only for others to read but for myself as well.

Comment: To make this answer valuable for others, split paragraphs up to make it easy to read. I will read it many times myself and I need all the help I can get. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo They are in paragraphs.

Comment: Yes, I meant that you could split them up to make them more easily accessible. Your 10:th is a thick, but important, brick.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sure thing; done! I formatted the code a little bit; quite a bit actually. We can consider the first one a `rough-draft`...

Comment: Excellent! Now, that's FAQ material. 

However "How often are you Casting from one type to another and back?" and such seem a bit aged.  The casting interface should (i.m.o.) be kept very limited.

Comment: @TedLyngmo True; but in any large scale 3D engine; sometimes you don't have but a choice to; and quite frequently. The main reason for this is your Window Size; and Aspect Ratios are typically in `unsigned int` `ScreenWidth x ScreenHeight` and `pixelsInX x pixlesInY` and most of your game content should be in `floats`; `double` not needed as `floating` point `precision` is typically enough to simulate any `3D` `Rendered` `Scenery`. Your time is initially in an `int` type but the casted to a double. For time calculations you want the higher `precision`. So there is a good amount of casting...

Comment: @TedLyngmo ...This also does account for game objects that inherit from a base class where you have to cast them back and forth between their base and derived types... For example you may have a base class of a `Weapon`, but derived you have `Gun`, `Sword`, `Bat`, `Axe`, however you want to store them as `shared_ptr` into some class  `MemoryManager's` member vector. So you need to cast them back and forth too. I have a working 3D Game Engine with a First Person Shooter built off of it that is almost 100k lines of code.

Comment: No doubt! You got me at `Lawnmower` (oh, random future inheritance). :-)